# iOS Fast auto enhance?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, filter, core-image

Because of the function of my app, I'm auto enhancing the full resolution image. On  pre-iPhone 5 devices, its taking forever (clocked at 71 seconds).

I'm using the standard auto enhancing code:

```
CIImage * image = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:uiImage];
NSArray * filters = [image autoAdjustmentFilters];
for (CIFilter * filter in filters) {
    [filter setValue:image forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    image = filter.outputImage;
}
CGImageRef cgImage = [_context createCGImage:image fromRect:[image extent]];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    UIImage * final = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage scale:uiImage.scale orientation:uiImage.imageOrientation];
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
    if (completion)completion(final);
});
```

When I pause the app, the 'createCGImage' method is taking forever.  How can I render the same output in much quicker time?

Comment: Note: this only appears to happen on very large images.  The time to enhance an image at 720x1280 was 3.7s, but at 1936x2592 it was 71s-80s

Comment: For one, the latter image has 5.4 times the pixels of the former, so you'd expect at least that much slower of a response. Also, one of the dimensions of your image exceeds the maximum texture size on older iOS devices (2048) so Core Image may need to fall back to a CPU-bound image processing path for portions that are run on the GPU normally. This would lead to a significant reduction in processing speed.

Comment: Is their a way to check if the image exceeds the max texture size before processing?

Comment: For Core Image, if you're using a CIContext that has been set up to run on the GPU only, `-inputImageMaximumSize` should return the maximum image size that is supported for this. Otherwise, if you set up and make current an OpenGL ES context, you can use `glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, &maxTextureSize);` to determine the maximum texture size of your current hardware.